# Ruby on Rails: How do you prefix named routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking to generate a link that has a prefix attached to the named route itself. Something like this to display the path "/old/recipes":

```
recipes_path(:prefix => "old/")  # the correct way should show "/old/recipes"
```

I don't want to touch the routes.rb file, but modify the named route with the prefix attached. Is that possible and how would you do it correctly?

**EDIT:** I'm using Rails 3. The reason for adding the optional prefix is I want to use the normal recipes_path as well. So I want to use both "/recipes" and "/old/recipes".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're going to run into a lot of pain if you don't want to touch the routes file, mainly because that's what Rails is going to reference when it tries to figure out where your route goes. I don't know of another way to do that, so here's the *config/routes.rb* code when you're convinced it's a good idea:

```
scope :path => "old" do
  resources :recipes
end
```

Now when you route to `recipes_path` it will go to `/old/recipes`, although this may not be what you're after. If that's the case, then you may want to chuck the `as` option on the end of this `scope`:

```
scope :path => "old", :as => "old" do
  resources :recipes
end
```

In which case, this route would now be `old_recipes_path`, still routing to `/old/recipes`.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. The reason is I want to add the optional prefix is that I'm also using the recipes_path as well. So I'm needing both "/recipes" and "/old/recipes" paths. Am I out of luck?

Comment: @sjsc: for both have the scoped one and the unscoped one, with the one you want recipes_path to go to defined first.

Comment: Thank you Ryan :) I completely missed your follow-up. Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, as a nice development tool, you can add the restful_routing gem to track your routes easier: https://rubygems.org/gems/restful_routing